# Loading files from a different partition

Tags: ruby, disk-partitioning, load-path

I'm working at `C:\(...)\Desktop`, and I need to `require` my scripts at `G:\scripts`. I tried to change the `$LOAD_PATH`:

```
$LOAD_PATH << 'G:\\scripts'
require 'filename'
```

and also the argument of `require`:

```
require 'G:\\scripts\\filename'
```

but I always get

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- dir_iterator (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from a.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

It works well if the directory is on `C:\` partition. What's happening here?